# Frequently encounter 'CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerErrorCurrentlyLoading' error 7 when calling CXCallDirectoryManager.reloadExtension

Tags: ios, callkit

I got error code 7 very frequently when calling reloadExtension on the CallDirectory Manager. And the extension enable spinner will always loading...

I'm using callkit extension to write data to calldirectory. I have 200-500 contacts which is saved to a shared app group which is used by both host app and the extension.

The host app will write data to this file. And in the beginRequest of the extension, I will add all identifications (number-label pairs) by calling context.addIdentificationEntry in a for loop. I have tried autoreleasepool and using dispatch async in batch, not works.

I have 3 files to store the data in NSArray to be added or removed.

```
1. First one is a file for all contacts, which should be used when the request is not incremental.

2. Second file is the incremental add, which will be used when it is a incremental request.

3. Third file is the records need to be removed.
```

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:self.groupIdentifier];
containerURL = [containerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CallDirectoryData"];
NSString* filePath = containerURL.path;
NSArray *list = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; // list is already sorted.
for(NSDictionary *record in list) {
    [context.addIdentificationEntry [record valueForKey: @"phone"] forLabel: @"label"]
}
```

Any suggestions about the initial setup or incremental best practice? Or how to make the loading time acceptable?

Comment: It turns out I called the **removeAllIdentification** in the **non incremental **reload. After remove this line, the extension works correctly

Comment: Thanks so much! I lost several hours while debugging this issue.